# How to compare object?

Tags: java, compare

I'm new to Java programming, I'm trying to learn how to make a BST. Here is my code:

Class TreeNode:

```
public void insert( Town d ) {

      if ( d.compareTo(data1) < 0 ) //ERROR HERE
      {
         if ( left == null )
            left = new TreeNode( d );
         else
            left.insert( d );
      }
         else if ( d.compareTo(data1) > 0 ) //ERROR HERE
      {
         if ( right == null )
            right = new TreeNode( d );
         else
            right.insert( d );
      }
     }
}
```

> The error is **Cannot find symbol**.

Comment: What is `data1`? Looks like an undefined variable (thus the root cause of your problem).

Comment: Please post the rest of your code.

Comment: Declare data1 as a valid variable. It should be of type 'Town' in your example so you can compare both of them.

Comment: see define a compareTo mehtod inside your town class as i mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that there is no variable called `data1`. From knowing how binary trees work, I would recommend defining a member of `TreeNode` called `data1` to hold the data for your node. Your `TreeNode` class would look like this:

```
public class TreeNode {
    private int data1;

    public TreeNode (int data) {
        data1 = data;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data1;
    }

    public void insert( Town d ) {
        if ( d.compareTo(data1) < 0 ) {
            if ( left == null )
                left = new TreeNode( d );
            else
                left.insert( d );
        } else if ( d.compareTo(data1) > 0 ) {
            if ( right == null )
                right = new TreeNode( d );
            else
                right.insert( d );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to gather from your question that you intended to insert a node to the left or right of `this` node. I explicitly used the keyword `this` in a few places where it is not required in order to demonstrate what I believe you intended to accomplish.

Assuming each TreeNode has a Town called `town`:

```
if (this.town.compareTo(d) < 0) 
{
    if (left == null)
        left = new TreeNode(d);
    else
        left.insert(d);
} 
else if (this.town.compareTo(d) > 0 ) 
{
    if (right == null)
        right = new TreeNode(d);
    else
        right.insert(d);
    }
}
```

Other answers are still correct - one of the symbols on the line you mentioned doesn't exist in the scope for which you are attempting to use it. It could be `data1`, or it could be your `compareTo()` method.

If Towns are ordered by population, you can use a neat Math trick to implement your compareTo.

```
public int compareTo(Town other) {
    return this.population - other.population;
}
```

Or, if Town's are ordered by name, you can reuse String's compareTo method.

```
    return this.name.compareTo(other.name);
```

In you have to implement a more complicated compareTo, simply return a negative int if `this` is less than `other`, zero if they are equal, or positive int if `this` is greater than `other`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Town class add a method called compareTo(Datatype data1).

```
public class Town {

public int compareTo(Town data1) {

    // compare both the object and return the coresponding value
    return 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can use the fonction .equals() on two objects that implements the generic java methods equals() and hashcode() in Java.

The hashcode() method is used to get an integer value of your object and the equals() method uses this hash(integer) to compare and return a boolean (wheter or not they are equal). You could then compare the objects with .equals()

```
public void insert( Town d ) {

  if ( d.equals(data1) < 0 ) //ERROR HERE
  {
     if ( left == null )
        left = new TreeNode( d );
     else
        left.insert( d );
  }
     else if ( d.equals(data1) > 0 ) //ERROR HERE
  {
     if ( right == null )
        right = new TreeNode( d );
     else
        right.insert( d );
  }
 }
}
```

Given that data is of the type Town of course. You can insert those two methods automtically with your IDE.

Here is a full explanation/example: http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html

Comment: and while equals() returns a boolean, what i meant is that hashcode() creates an hash (integer) with the object. Edited to make it more clear.

Sorry if this does not answer the question, given the title I thought you were having trouble comparing the objects.